# Azure AVD post configuration automation

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, dsc

I work for a little to medium size client with an azure eco system and try to find a good way
to make configuration to AVD after there creation.

I know there are tools like ansible but for the little number of server we have that too big.

I would like to know what are you using to make configuration on vm ? I'm not an expert and
what I write here his what I've found and that may not be the way to use these tools. That's why
I'm asking.

What we have tried so far :

```
1: The custom script extension (The most valuable for the moment)
    This is the best at the moment but a lot of scripting to do 
    to make it work dynamically. 

2: The dsc
    That cool when we dont have to install new module one the vm.

3: AIB
    We are using the image from the store so no cumstom image to build and to maintain.
```

So what are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the IAC tool(Terraform and Azure ARM template ) here you can write you own code to do the configuration in VM. Its works on Incremental mode. You can also use [***Chef***](https://www.chef.io/) automation tool to do the configuration on your VM that works on Pull based mechanism.

You can refer this Document to [***Configure Azure Virtual Desktop with Terraform***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/configure-azure-virtual-desktop)